# Dropdown value need to pass in the repeater control bind method

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

ProductCategory - 
                                       
                                        KiloGrams - 
                                        Quantity - --%>
                                    
                                        Selling Price : ₹
                                        Shipment : --%>

C# Code

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        ProductID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ID"]);
        
        PopulateImages2Bind();
        
    }  

}
```

private void PopulateImages2Bind()
{

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DC_ProductView_SELECT_V1", cn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID", ProductID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Userid", "");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", "4");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Conversion", TextBox2.Text);
    SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DA.Fill(dtttt);
        // dt = sliderhelper.GetsliderImage();  
        Repeater3.DataSource = dtttt;
        Repeater3.DataBind();
    
}
```

private DataTable GetData(string query)
{
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SanConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

```
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                return dt;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

protected void OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
{

```
            //Find the DropDownList in the Repeater Item.
            DropDownList ddlCountries = (e.Item.FindControl("DropDownList1") as DropDownList);
            ddlCountries.DataSource = this.GetData("select ProductConversion+'-'+ProductWeight AS ProductConversion  from DcConversion");
            ddlCountries.DataTextField = "ProductConversion";
            ddlCountries.DataValueField = "ProductConversion";
            ddlCountries.DataBind();

            
        }

}
```

---

---

```
In this selected index Conversion_cart_SelectedIndexChanged am getting the value in the textbox2 , once the dropdown is selected i need to get the value and need to pass in the PopulateImages2Bind (@Conversion) parameter.
Basically the value need to pass and bind the PopulateImages2Bind 

the page is like if user selected the quantity in the dropdown go and take the price for the quantity and show
for example 
1 = 20rs
2 = 40rs
3 = 60rs
```

if any details need please let me know will share you to clear my doubts
how to achieve this ? please someone help .............................

Comment: I assume the question is that when you fill out the repeater, you ALSO after fillig the combo box need to set its value for the given row? do that right after you fill the como box in your itemdata bound code, or set the combo box text value to a expression (Eval) in the markup. Since your item data bound JUST grabbed the combo box then right after you databind the combo, then set the value of the combo box to the correct product conversion value at that point in time. You are good to fill out the combo box, but you fail to set it value from that row in the table at that point in time.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal - can you please explain in the code level , how to complete this task. actually am ne to the program coding ,